# execute a function once in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

i have to develop a web application using Vaadin 7, and i have a function that store the data in the database and it should be executed just once when i run the project but not in every time i refresh the page.
i try to write this function in the constructor like this:

```
 public class Dmav_3UI extends UI {
  public class Dmav_3UI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = Dmav_3UI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
    }
    public Dmav_3UI(){
            myFunction();

        }
```

but it still run every time i refresh the page.
can you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotate the UI with [@PreserveOnRefresh](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+an+application+that+preserves+state+on+refresh). The [documentation states](http://vaadin.com/download/release/7.2/7.2.0/docs/api/com/vaadin/annotations/PreserveOnRefresh.html) that unless this is used, a new UI instance is created on each page refresh.

Comment: No problem. The only thing that came to me now, is that this will execute once for each new user session. If you'd want to execute it only once when the app is started then we might have to use a servlet/listener

Comment: it work in the way that i need, so thank you for this tip :D :D

Comment: Then I'm glad I could be of assistance